# Is there a CSPRNG capable of generating a large sequence of numbers from a single seed?

Tags: random-number-generator

In my CS course i am in dire need of a CSPRNG that can create N numbers starting from a single key.

Something like this:

> CSPRNG(x):
>
> Input 64 bit int;
>
> Output Array of CSR 64 bit Ints;

Does something like this exists? Which ones?

Or is almost every CSPRNG like this?

Comment: If this is to run on a normal computer, any reason you can't just use the standard built in *nix or Windows ones?  Or the ones in common programming languages that can be user seeded?

Comment: Its to run on a regular computer, yes. Well if i understood your question correctly, i dont really know if i can use the built in functions since i dont know if they are CSPRNG or just PRNG or even secure for that matter. Thats mainly the reason i asked the question. But eventually this is just for a theoretical basis, since the code im building is more a Proof-of-concept than anything else. Now, are the built in RNG functions in linux Crypto-secure?

Comment: Yes, the RNG in Linux is called /dev/urandom and is actually a CSPRNG.  But.  It and any language that uses it (like Java and Python) cannot reseed the generator.  It will always be unpredictable and this might not be what you want.  I use my own custom CSPRNG that's a Pearson Hash feeding SHA256(RC4) giving a 1684 bit state which is easily seeded.

Answer (score 6):

A PRNG, by definition, outputs a sequence of arbitrary length from a finite state. So you can get as many chunks of 64 bits as you may want from any PRNG. Or, said otherwise: if you have something that gets stuck at some point, then it is not a PRNG.

Such a PRNG is said to be "cryptographically secure" (that's the "CS" in "CSPRNG") if the output bits are unpredictable; that is, given *n* successive output bits from the PRNG, it is computationally unfeasible to predict the next bit with probability substantially better than 0.5. If you use a 64-bit seed, then there are only 2<sup>64</sup> possible initial states for the PRNG, a large number, but not practically infinitely so. It is expensive but technologically possible to enumerate all possible 2<sup>64</sup> seed values, and get the corresponding PRNG output. In that case, it suffices to try all these seed values to pinpoint the one which produces the PRNG output observed so far; afterwards, the future output of the PRNG can be predicted with 100% accuracy, which means that the PRNG is not cryptographically secure.

If you want a really secure PRNG, then you need a larger seed space (typically 128 bits or more). Take care that a big seed is not *sufficient* to get a CSPRNG; it is merely a necessary condition, to prevent the exhaustive search attack described above.

For some examples of CSPRNG, see [NIST SP 800-90A](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90a/rev-1/final). That document actually separates the "PRNG" part (they call it "DRBG", the "D" meaning "deterministic") from the seeding, and enforce regular re-seeding. You can also get a CSPRNG from any good stream cipher (e.g. the ones from the [eSTREAM portfolio](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/)) or by running a block cipher (with large blocks, 128 bits or more) in CTR mode.

There are a number of published PRNG (e.g. the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)) which are *not* meant for cryptography, and fail to be unpredictable by attackers. Such PRNG are good enough for non-adversarial situations (e.g. simulation of physics experiments) but not for anything related to security.

Comment: Thank you for distinguishing between a CSPRNG that produces predictable output - e.g. a stream cipher - and a CSPRNG that is used to produce random numbers. That distinction is not made often enough and can lead to real problems when they are confused (e.g. `getRawKey` where a PRNG is used to derive keys that are just *slightly* more random than expected).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This solves another doubt i had. The seed can be 128 bits, even more when the idea is fully built, i used 64 bit in the example just as an example. In hindsight i should have used 128.

Answer (score 2):

I will go against what everybody is saying here and explain how you can use only 64 bit seed securely.

What you cannot do is use a 64 bit internal state. This can be brute forced. And becomes easier to the more data points you produce, you don't have to break the initial state, any intermediate state is good enough to figure out all subsequent output.

But if you have a large internal state, say 256 bit to be on the safe side, such attacks on the state are impractical. You now only need to convert 64 bit seed to a 256 bit state once. You can do this with any slow KDF. These are considered secure even for passwords with less than 64 bits of entropy. And are fine for 64 bits by virtue of being so slow. You may or not be allowed to add a salt, but a constant pepper is also useful.

64 bits is on the edge of brute forcible for fast cryptographic operations. It can be made clearly outside the realm of possibility by using a deliberately slow KDF. And you only need to use the slow operation once, continuing with an efficient CSPRNG with large state of your choice.

Comment: You can add a few bits to the effective security (not shannon randomness of course), but enough to bring it to 256 bits? In order to increase the effective strength by a single bit, you have to double the time it takes for the KDF to run. Getting to 256 bits would require you use $2^{192}$ iterations of whatever function you use for your KDF, which is completely impractical. Simply getting to 112 bits (the security of 3DES) would require $2^{48}$ iterations of your KDF function. Also, what in the world would you need a salt and pepper for in this scenario...? This isn't some database.

Comment: I didn't say we would reach 256 bit of security. I said we will make it impractical to brute force. A custom pepper is used to make sure nobody will bring a generic rainbow table from somewhere else. And any work to attack our implementation will be specific to our implementation. If we make the KDF run for 1 second in a modern CPU it will take 2^64 cpu seconds. At 10 cents/cpu-hour it will cost you $5e14 to brute force. Sounds safe to me.

Comment: Rainbow tables are not issues for anything that uses an actual random seed. They only matter for human-created, short passphrases. A rainbow table is a type of hash table that matches common passwords with their hashes, allowing fast lookups. There would be no way to precompute $2^{64}$ values in a rainbow table, so a salt would be entirely useless. I'm assuming you don't believe OP is going to use a human-created _password_ to seed a CSPRNG?

Comment: You are both claiming you can brute force 2^64 bits with a slow KDF. And claim you can't build rainbow tables? You do know the compute cost of building a rainbow table is similar to that of a single brute force.

Comment: But building a rainbow table with $2^{64}$ entries would be _way_ to big to store on any conceivable device. Even if we did have technology to store it, it would grant no speedup whatsoever and would actually slow things down (as a table lookup is faster, and generating a rainbow table takes more power than just brute force). I suggest you read https://security.stackexchange.com/a/440/165253. The Wikipedia article on the subject is also useful. Rainbow tables have a very specific purpose for a space-time tradeoff.

Comment: Defense against time-memory tradeoff were a minor point in my answer yet it stands. Even if I store only $2^{40}$ pairs, I can reduce the online phase from $2^{64}$ to $2^{48}$ using a simple curve $TM^2=N^2$ that's with storage I have at home. with massive storage arrays we could do better.

Comment: You are demonstrating that you do not understand what the purpose of a rainbow table is. It is _not_ used for **fully-random, uniform, machine-generated seeds** no matter how small. Your answer regarding a slow KDF is not an issue (though I think it may be impractical in this case), rather it's your claim that a pepper is in any way useful. Note also that a pepper is only useful for a large number of hashes stored outside of a database. When used for a single application or per-application, it is called a salt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73645/discussion-between-forest-and-meir-maor).

Answer (score 1):

A 64 bit input is too small to be cryptographically secure, but you can use a CSPRNG to get statistically good random numbers (or increase your seed size).  For example, just zero extend your seed and use that as a key for AES-CTR.  Running AES-CTR gives you a statistically random stream of bits which you can take in 64 bit chunks as your numbers.

A little more verbosely:

1. Let $k$ be your seed zero-extended to 128 bits.
2. Let $c_i \leftarrow \text{AES}_k(i)$
3. For each block $c_x$ split it into two 64 bit values. That is, $r_i \leftarrow \text{MaybeShiftAndMask}(i\%2, c_{i/2})$.

Your random values are $r_i$.

Comment: Thank you! This explains a lot. Is AES-CTR really a good CSPRNG? Even with AES being cracked lately? Or does it not matter for the PRNG?

Comment: AES has not been "cracked lately".

Comment: As for if any stream cipher is a good CSPRNG: Using a stream cipher for random bits can be fine - certainly fine statistically.  Where they suffer is under various threat models.  For example, there is no way to incorporate additional randomness so the birthday bound is an issue.  Also there is no backtracking resistance meaning an adversary who compromises your RNG (i.e. the system) can compute all past random values.  There are slightly more complex designs that do not have these weaknesses but it didn't sound like you cared.  Other answers include relevant pointers, such as SP800-90